# Main differences in Mavis shuttlecocks

Tags: equipment, badminton

1. What are the main differences of Yonex Mavis 350, 370 and 2000 plastic shuttlecocks?
2. Every type has nylon in **two colours**: **white** and **yellow**, what is the purpose of this?
3. It says that Mavis 2000 series have the closest resemblance to feathers, but which type to which type, meaning:

   - **green 2000** equivalent to Yonex feather,
   - **blue 2000** to Yonex feather and
   - **red 2000** to Yonex feather.

Comment: Your post actually contains four questions. Please try to stick to one question at a time.

Comment: Technically, there are three questions, not four, but your point of view is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let met start by saying that a plastic shuttle cock (until now) can never match the shuttle flight / behavior of a feather shuttle cock.

1. As for the different types (title), this indicates the apparent quality different by [Yonex](http://www.yonex.com/sports/badminton/products/badminton/shuttlecocks/nylon-shuttlecocks).
2. Yellow is added for visibility purposes, especially against contrasting back ground colors.
3. The different colors that are used on the cork, indicate the speed of the shuttle. Green being slow, blue being average and red being fast. This is best compared to the different speeds the feather shuttle cocks have: 77, 78, 79 etc. See this answer I gave on that topic: https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2890/1455
4. Comparing it to a feather shuttle cock makes no sense. Perhaps that's better answered by Yonex themselves.

<sub>Note: I'm not affiliated to the vendor mentioned in this post.</sub>